# Calling a C# SOAP webservice from PHP generates bad data

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am working on a new website and I need to call a webservice made by a "sub contractor"

part of the WDSL:

```
<s:element name="Send_Question">
   <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="spm" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fylke" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="username" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="s:int"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="s:string"/>
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
 </s:element>
 <s:element name="Send_QuestionResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Send_QuestionResult">
             <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                   <s:any/>
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
       <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="errorCode" type="s:int"/>
       <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="errorDescription" type="s:string"/>
     </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

POST /WebService/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: domain.no
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://domain/WebService/Send_Question"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Send_Question xmlns="https://domain/WebService/">
      <spm>string</spm>
      <fylke>string</fylke>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <errorCode>int</errorCode>
      <errorDescription>string</errorDescription>
    </Send_Question>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I haw tried a couple of different ways of getting it to work here is what seems to work best at the moment.

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://domain.no/WebService/WebService.asmx?WSDL", array('trace' => 1));


$UsrName = 'someUserName';
$PassWd = 'password';

$errorCode = 0;
$errorDescription = '';
try{
$params = array(
            'spm' => 'Dette er en hardkodet test', //$Sporsmal;
            'fylke' => 'hardkodet fylke', //$fylke;
            'username' => md5($UsrName),
            'password' => md5($PassWd),     
            'errorCode' => $errorCode,
            'errorDescription' => $errorDescription
        );
         $result  = $client->Send_Question($params);
         return $result;
}catch (SoapFault $fault){
        echo '<br/>En feil oppstod<br/>';
        echo $client->__getLastRequest() .'<br/>';
        echo $fault->faultcode . ' - ' . $fault->faultstring . ' - ' .$fault->detail;
    }
```

But all I get is **soap:Server - Server was unable to process request. ---> Bad Data. -**
From past experiance I'm guessing the problem lies with the "errorCode" and "ErrorDescription"

And $client->__getLastRequest() dumps the raw walues with no xml or "SOAP envelope"

Comment: Try `$result  = $client->__soapCall('Send_Question', $params);`

Comment: Now I get this soap:Server - Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToUnescape -

Comment: Try removing `errorDescription` in the `$params` array. When you pass it, it is expecting a string. Since `minOccurs="0"` you should be able to just remove it.

Comment: Same error from the Catch statement

Comment: Hm, try passing a random string instead of removing it.

Comment: nope still the same.
And with the old code "$result  = $client->Send_Question($params);" I get bad request, with your code I get "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToUnescape" 

However I notised that the param 'spm' is not printed by __getLastRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this turned out to be a little mix of different things. and not weary good error messages.

my code ended up beeing as follows.

```
try{
         $Send_Question = $client->Send_Question;
         $Send_Question->spm = $Sporsmal;
         $Send_Question->fylke = $fylke;
         $Send_Question->username = $usernm;
         $Send_Question->password = $passwd;
         $Send_Question->errorCode = &$errorCode;
         $Send_Question->errorDescription = &$errorDescription;

         $result = $client->Send_Question($Send_Question);


        return $result;
    }catch (SoapFault $fault){
        echo '<br/>error ocoured<br/>';
        //echo '<br/>' . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . '<br/>';
        //echo '<strong>Request:\n</strong><br/>' . $client->__getLastRequest() .'\n<br/>';
        //echo '<strong>Response:\n</strong><br/>' . $client->__getLastResponse() .'\n<br/>';
        //echo '<strong>Feilmelding fra "SoapFault"</strong> ' . $fault->faultcode . ' - ' . $fault->faultstring . ' - ' .$fault->detail;
    }
```

but the main problem turned out to be that the username and password was not correctly encrypted. MD5 and tripleDES was needed.